# How to implement Google Tag Manager In android app

Tags: android, google-tag-manager

How to add a Google TagManager in android application. Can anyone tel me the step by step procedure to do this. I already have GTM account and created the container and the version but I don't what code I need to add in my application and where I need to add the codes? I am using google analytics for this app and its working fine. Only problem is GTM.

Thanks a lot in advance

Comment: Did you read [this](https://developers.google.com/tag-manager/android/v4/)?

Comment: Yeah @BenitoBertoli I read that but for me its confusing. I don't know what is singleton and the pending result at all. And I don't know where I need to add that code. If there is any step by step tutorial then it will be more helpful.

Comment: Could you please tell me how to implement the google tag manager in the android application

Answer (score 0):

Here is pretty nice tutorial: https://developers.google.com/tag-manager/android/v3/#add-sdk
There are two version v3 and v4 , I think v3 is simplier.
Here is siplified steps
1.First you need to do all stuff from acount.
2.Then in app create a default container.
3.Open it when app starts
4. And send some events

so follow tutorial, and then maybe u will have more concrete questions